# <t:selectOneRadio submit issue in IE8

Tags: jsf, internet-explorer-8, ajax4jsf

I'm using tomahawk `<t:selectOneRadio>` as follows:

```
<t:selectOneRadio 
     id="sorid" onclick="myForm.submit();"
    value="#{myBean.property}" style="float: left;padding-right: 5px;">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.option_1}"
        itemValue="option1" id="option1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.option_2}"
        itemValue="option2" id="option2" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.option_3}"
        itemValue="option3" id="option3" />
    <a4j:support event="oncomplete" reRender="chart"/>
</t:selectOneRadio>
```

The form is submited but the backing bean property is never changed. This only happens in IE wether or not I give extra clicks on the page. I've tried with event="onclick" also. I've tried adding this.blur(); to the selectOneRadio onclick actions.

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

**Remove** the `onclick` handler. It's only colliding with Ajax support. Just let `<a4j:support>` do the job instead during the `click` event.

```html
<t:selectOneRadio 
     id="sorid"
    value="#{myBean.property}" style="float: left;padding-right: 5px;">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.option_1}"
        itemValue="option1" id="option1" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.option_2}"
        itemValue="option2" id="option2" />
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{bundle.option_3}"
        itemValue="option3" id="option3" />
    <a4j:support event="click" reRender="chart"/>
</t:selectOneRadio>
```

*(note that the event name does by itself **not** have the `on` prefix, this only applies to attribute names of the HTML elements which should refer a script which should be executed when the event occurs)*

Comment: It works both ways in a "clean" page. The problem here appears to be related with existing javascript errors that don't show up in firefox, but do show up in IE.

Comment: The onclick approach will still send 2 requests. One synchronous form submit which you initiated by `onclick` and one ajax change request which you initiated by `<a4j:support>`. Which one arrives the first is unspecified. Just don't mix them up at all. Remove the `onclick`. As to investigating Firefox JS errors, just install [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com). There it is for.